# Running AHCI breaks SMART monitors?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ahci, intel-rst

I'm running [this](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H77M-D3H-rev-11#support-dl) Intel H77 motherboard and Win7x64.  I had BIOS configured to run SATA in IDE mode, so Intel RST was complaining.  I just switched BIOS to run AHCI and updated the RST drivers, and now there's a Toshiba SMART monitoring process (apparently `TosSSDAlert.exe`, but might also relate to processes `TosSENotify.exe`, `TosSmartSrv.exe`) popping up with the following `Error Notification` (screenshot below):

> Unable to get disk information, can not use the alert feature.

Should I even care about a SMART monitor if I'm running Intel RST?  If so, what should I do about this Toshiba monitor complaint?  (SATA devices on this machine include two spinning Toshiba drives and one Samsung SSD.)

[image: TOSHIBA SMART Error]

Comment: What does the Toshbia software after to do with Intel RST?

Comment: @Ramhound: Intel RST demands AHCI mode.  When I configure the BIOS for AHCI the Toshiba software complains it can't work, even though it works fine in IDE.  I have no clue if there's a relationship between RST and the Toshiba monitor; I'm just offering it as an explanation of why I did what I did.

Comment: Test your setup with [GSmartMonitorTools](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/) or use [hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to get status of SMART. If it works (and it should because AHCI isn't a barrier to get SMART status) then get rid of bulky Toshiba monitor and use some of third party monitors like an [HDDHealth](http://panterasoft.com/hdd-health/)

Comment: @Alex - Good call: even `wmic diskdrive get status` works, so I guess it's a quirk in the Toshiba software.  Post as an answer so I can accept your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your setup with [GSmartMonitorTools](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/) or you can use [hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to get status of HDD via [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes. If it works (and it should, because [AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) isn't a barrier to get [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status) then get rid of bulky Toshiba's monitor and use some of third party monitors like an [HDDHealth](http://panterasoft.com/hdd-health/) or similar.

My personal opinion is that [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status of any HDD or SSD should be monitored continuously regardless of HDD's age. (It may fail in a 3 months or it may work 7-8 years) So, it better to be informed as soon as possible to avoid data loss.

Comment: I just tried HDDHealth, which hasn't been updated since 2014, and it was unable to read any properties of my drives.

Comment: Yes, it pretty old one, but it still works for many HDD and SSD. The best SMART IMO it is [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/), it works on all platforms and well supported. I usually run it on windows from scheduler on periodic basis or  use it as a service by employing [this](https://github.com/deajan/smartmontools-win) wrapper